# Functional analysis proof for $L^p$ spaces and Schur property.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

It is easy to construct an example in $L^2(\Omega)$ (where $\Omega$ is a bounded box in $\mathbb{R}^n$) for which weak convergence holds but strong does not. My question is: is there a general property of the $L^p$ spaces or a purely functional analytic proof of this fact?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are asking. First of all, you are asking only in the case of Lebesgue measure or also in the case of $L^p$ for a general measure $\mu$? If you need a counterexample for all $1\leq p<\infty$ in the case of Lebesgue measure, $\sin(nx)$ should do the trick in 1 dimension, similar examples can be found for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Or you are asking for a proof that this spaces do not satisfy Schur property, without showing explicitly a counterexample?

Comment: I am interested $L^p$ with the lebesgue measure, but more general argument also are useful.
I want a proof that show that this spaces do not satisfy the Schur property without showing explicitly a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $L_p(\Omega)$ contains a subspace isomorphic to $\ell_2$. For example, take the closed span of a sequence of independent, symmetric, two-valued random variables (and use Kchinchine's inequality). Then you may use your favourite proof for $\ell_2$.